# Graph removal lemma

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, extremal-graph-theory

The graph removal lemma says that for any graph $H$ and any $\epsilon>0$, there is a $\delta>0$ such that any $n$-vertex graph which contains at most $\delta n^{v(H)}$ copies of $H$ can be made $H$-free by removing at most $\epsilon n^2$ edges. My question is: if a graph contains at most $n^{v(H)-\mu}$ copies of $H$ for some $\mu>0$, how many edges should we remove in order to remove all copies of $H$?